# search for variable from list write line to file

Tags: python

When going through a list with `for x in list`, I am having a problem with:

```
if x in Invalid_names_file:
    ISP_names_file.write(str(x))
```

If I replace `if` with `for` then I get the entire contents of `Invalid_names_file` written into `ISP_names_file`.

Here is my code:

```
def isp_email_names():
    with open('Invalid_names_file', 'r') as Invalid_names_file:
        with open('ISP_names_file', 'w') as ISP_names_file:
            for x in one_ip_each():
                if x in Invalid_names_file:
                    ISP_names_file.write(str(x))
                    ISP_names_file.flush()
        ISP_names_file.closed
    Invalid_names_file.closed
```

The `one_ip_each` variable is my list, that come from a module that I have imported.

I can print this list at the end of the script to make sure that it's working, yet can't get any input into the write file.

I will be putting more `for` statements behind this, so I don't mind that it's just the last `x` in my list that shows up in the file when I cut it out to see that it's working.

The file does get written to disk, nothing in it with the `if ...`, whole file-1 with the `for ...`

i should have been clearer in my original post.

my list->

```
['192.168.122.21', '192.168.122.22', '192.168.122.25']
```

and some of the file that i'm trying to go through->

```
Jul 25 11:29:02 testing sshd[1345]: Invalid user JoseMartinez from 192.168.122.25
Jul 25 11:29:03 testing sshd[1347]: Invalid user BillyCarter from 192.168.122.25
Jul 25 11:24:26 testing sshd[1094]: Invalid user DavidFlores from   192.168.122.21
Jul 25 11:25:05 testing sshd[1108]: Invalid user Nicole from 192.168.122.22
```

trying to do 'for x in list' find lines with x in it and print the whole line to a file.

Comment: 1. You don't need to close your files when you use `with` statement for opening the files. 2. what's in your list and how you want to check the membership for its items? file object are iterator-like objects and you cannot check the member ship with `in` in these objects.

Comment: Tried to fix up your question a bit, but heck, there's still quite a bit of mess left...

Comment: my list when printed:  ['192.168.122.21', '192.168.122.22', '192.168.122.25'] and a line that i'm trying to search through:  Jul 25 11:29:03 testing sshd[1347]: Invalid user BillyCarter from 192.168.122.25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

final code that works->

```
def isp_email_names():
    with open('Invalid_names_file', 'r') as Invalid_names_file:
        with open('ISP_names_file', 'w') as ISP_names_file:
            for x in one_ip_each():
                for line in Invalid_names_file:
                    if x in line:
                        ISP_names_file.writelines(str(line))
                        ISP_names_file.flush()
            ISP_names_file.closed
        Invalid_names_file.closed

isp_email_names()
```

don't know why i have to call the function to have it write to disk though.  will try to figure that out later.

thank you everyone for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

`Invalid_names_file` is an iterator. So after first `if x in ...` this iterator is empty and all following tests results in `False`. Read your file into a list first and then test each line with the `in` operator and not only the list elements.

```
def isp_email_names():
    with open('Invalid_names_file', 'r') as Invalid_names_file:
        Invalid_names_file = list(Invalid_names_file)
    with open('ISP_names_file', 'w') as ISP_names_file:
        for ip in one_ip_each():
            for line in Invalid_names_file:
                if ip in line:
                    ISP_names_file.write(line)
```

Comment: when i use the set(...) i am getting a syntax error with the ^ pointing to the p in set(1.strip()

Comment: whis is a lower letter L not a 1.

Comment: @emetib: now your question is a totally other one, so I have to rewrite the answer completely.

Comment: thank you daniel.  i was trying to do that last night and was getting frustrated, printing whole file-1 to file-2.  took a look at it again today and figured it out.  didn't have to make it into a list() though.  i'll post my answer at the end.

Answer (score 0):

A not so elegant solution, running in O(N) run time, but having it check in regards to if x is contained in a readline. Sorry in advance for the not so elegant solution and hope it works.

```
def isp_email_names():
    with open('Invalid_names_file', 'r') as Invalid_names_file:
        with open('ISP_names_file', 'w') as ISP_names_file:
            for x in one_ip_each():
                if str(x) in Invalid_names_file.readline():
                    ISP_names_file.write(str(x))
                    ISP_names_file.flush()
```

Comment: def isp_email_names():
    one_ip_each = ['192.168.122.21', '192.168.122.22', '192.168.122.25']
    with open('Invalid_names_file', 'r') as Invalid_names_file:
        with open('ISP_names_file', 'w') as ISP_names_file:
            for x in one_ip_each:
                if str(x) in Invalid_names_file.readline():
                    ISP_names_file.write(str(x))
                    ISP_names_file.flush()
I tried this given your list from a comment, worked, not sure what's wrong given it wrote for me.

Comment: this is the whole thing put together.  probably very sloppy, yet just start to program. [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwhDqxZzf5XHeEhyVzd3dXBjQm8/view?usp=sharing) [/link] you can open it with the drive notepad

Comment: will write the file to disk, yet only with the ip and not the whole line.  have to put a print(isp_email_names()) for the last line.

Comment: Oh that's cause you are writing the value str(x) which is your list of ip arrays, store the readline and write that instead of your str(x)

Comment: i'm lost.  i'll keep reading and maybe i'll be able to figure it out later.  thank you for your help.